# itunes-search API Android

Tags: java, android, itunes

Due to unexpected circumstances I find myself coding an app for Android in Java(my experience is 0 with Android or Java), I´ve been doing so far very good, but now I´m stuck with something. I´m trying to Parse the iTunes Search API, and I´ve downloaded a library for doing so:

https://github.com/mdewilde/itunes-search

But I can´t manage to get the single parameters after making the Search(), this is my code:

```
Response response = new Search("La+vereda+de+la+puerta+de+atras").execute();
response.setResults(response.getResults());
Result result = new Result();
System.out.println(result.getArtistName().toString()); // Returns nil
```

Thank you very much in advanced

Comment: You create a new Result and read the ArtistName from it. This is of course null. Without knowing the API I would guess that response.getResults() gives you the data that is returned by the search and that you have to iterate over this to print all the received data.

Comment: @FlorianS. Your guess is right, but it wouldn´t make much sense to iterate over it, when the API already has a Result model, where all the parameters that iTunes Returns are already defined.

Comment: Isn't the response.getResults() some kind of Collection with multiple results that are matching  your query? Just iterate over that Collection and then for each Result object you could access its parameters like ArtistName, Title or whatever.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This would be the correct way of doing that:

```
Response response = new Search("La+vereda+de+la+puerta+de+atras").execute();
List<Result> results = response.getResults();

if (results != null && results.size() > 0) {
    for(Result result : results) {
        System.out.println(result.getArtistName().toString());
    }
} else {
    System.out.println("No results found :(");
}
```